# Position sticky broken in Firefox 57

Tags: css

I'm trying to use position sticky to make a sticky table header.

The following jsfiddle works in Chrome v64, but isn't working in Firefox v57.

https://jsfiddle.net/b5fv94m0/

Is there some additional CSS I'm missing to make it work in Firefox?

CSS

```
.container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you aware that position: sticky is an experimental API and should not be used in production? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky Browser Compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility & https://caniuse.com/#search=position%3Asticky

Comment: Ah yes I see now. The issue mainly relates to sticky not working for table elements yet.

Comment: This has been working with tables since Firefox 59.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the browsers are not supporting this `position: sticky` attribute as mentioned it's an experimental API. Instead of that use `position: fixed;` for making it `sticky`.

Check [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) for browser compatibility.

Comment: `position: sticky` is definitely working in Firefox, and has been since v56. This isn't the issue @andrewdavey was having.

Answer (score 0):

position:sticky

This css is not compatible to all browser so better use `position: fixed`